# How to write sql join query using HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate

I've got two entities `AddressEntity` and `CompanyEntity`.

Address entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6149442393833549397L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "post")
    private String post;

    @Column(name = "street", nullable = false)
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "building_nr", nullable = false)
    private Integer buildingNr;

    @Column(name = "flat_nr")
    private Integer flatNr;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Company entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class CompanyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3635072833730133590L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private AddressEntity address = new AddressEntity();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<DescriptionEntity> descriptions = new HashSet<DescriptionEntity>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<EmployeeEntity> employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeEntity>();

}
```

I want to `select all addresses which are used by companies` like in this SQL query `SELECT a.city, c.name FROM address a INNER JOIN company c ON c.address_id=a.id;` but using HQL query (I want to use JOIN, not WHERE). How can I do it? I want to select addresses using address table, not company table. I know that I can select addresses using company table like this `select c.address.city, c.name from CompanyEntity c` or using WHERE `select a.city, c.name from CompanyEntity c, AddressEntity a WHERE c.address.id=a.id`.

Comment: if you want to select addresses used by companies using address table u need to add relation between adress and company in address entity

Comment: @pepuch Why don't you write criteria?

Comment: I'm totally new in Hibernate. Can you please write your ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(CompanyEntity.class);
c.createAlias("address", "address");
List<CompanyEntity> companies = c.list();
```

This will give you list of `CompanyEntities` having at least one `AddressEntity`.

If you add the following line:

```
c.criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("address"));
```

You will get a List of `AddressEntities` by doing `c.list()`.

Tell me if you need something else.